# Rails application not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a new application that is giving me errors when I do

```
rails server
```

Here is the error:

```
/home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/agenadinik in PATH, mode 040777
/home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/agenadinik in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval': /home/agenadinik/workspace/udfr/config.ru:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
    from /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
    from /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
    from /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:248:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
    from /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
    from /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It seems to be complaining about my config.ru file.  Here it is:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Udfr::Application
```

Here is my environment.rb file:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /java/
  require 'rubygems'
  RAILS_CONNECTION_ADAPTERS = %w(jdbc)
end

# Initialize the rails application
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
Udfr::Application.initialize!
```

I changed that file according to these instructions:
http://www.digitalsanctum.com/2007/07/24/jruby-deploying-a-rails-application-on-tomcat/
Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Can you include your environment.rb file as well?

Comment: Is that really your entire `environment.rb` file? It looks like it's missing an `end` at the end if it. Also: calling `initialize!` in it is wrong, that's not what `environment.rb` does... `application.rb` does that.

Comment: Appears to be some kind of syntax error in your file, most likely a bracket that has not been closed. You can test individual files to see if the Ruby interpreter can deal with them, for instance: `ruby config.ru` If it complains about something other than syntax, the syntax is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you followed are for Rails 2 and will not work with your Rails 3 app.

The [updated instructions](http://gregmoreno.ca/deploy-a-rails-3-sqlite3-application-in-tomcat-using-jruby/) for getting Ruby on Rails to work on jruby are to edit your gemfile and place your gem requirements there.

In `Gemfile`:

```
if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
end
```

Then run `bundle`.